# Facebook post to page error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am going insane...

After Googling, searching here and pulling each of my hairs out one by one, I'm stuck.

I am trying to automate posts to a Facebook page and am calling the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXX&scope=publish_actions,publish_pages,manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com
```

Followed by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&client_secret=XXXX&code=XXXXXX
```

This successfully gives me the access token, but when I try to use the Graph API explorer to post to the page (of which I am an Admin), I get the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I've tried different permissions, different roles for page users and about everything else I can think of! Could anyone shed some light on this? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: You need to get a page access token first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try **page access_token** for facebook page publishing, not user access_token. 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/accounts

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear for everyone else the last step in this process is to call https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXX as Kib says.Then call a POST query using https://graph.facebook.com/v.2.3/{page_id}/feed using the access token given to you in the previous step.